# Arrays y objetos dentro del resultado de un JSON POSTGRESQL

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonobject, jsonarray

Estoy generando un json apartir de una consulta sql, dicha consulta funciona perfecto.
Pero lo que estoy intentando generar, son varios objectos y arrays dentro del resultado del json.

Es decir,

cuando ejecuto la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT to_json(Q.*) FROM
(SELECT p.product_id                                      AS id,
       p.title,
       p.description,
       Concat('https://kiero.co/detalle/', p.product_id) AS link,
       f.url                                             AS image_link,
       igs.selection_url                                 AS
       additional_image_link,
       'in_stock'                                        AS availability,
       Round(( p.price / 3540 ) * 3800)                  AS cost_of_good_sold,
       Cast(Round(p.price) AS VARCHAR(50))               AS price,
       Round(( p.price / 36 ))                           AS installment,
       c.NAME                                            AS
       google_product_category,
       Replace(c.fullname, '/', ' > ')                   AS product_type,
       CASE
         WHEN brand IS NULL THEN 'kiero'
         ELSE brand
       END                                               AS brand,
       CASE
         WHEN p.upc = '0' THEN NULL
         ELSE p.ean
       END                                               AS gtin,
       Concat('API_', f.product_id)                      AS mpn,
       'new'                                             AS condition,
       CASE
         WHEN p.is_adult_product = 1 THEN 'Si'
         ELSE 'No'
       END                                               AS adult,
       CASE
         WHEN p.price > 5500000 THEN 'Price 5.5M +'
         WHEN p.price > 1500000
              AND ( p.price < 5500000 ) THEN 'Price 1.5 - 5.5M'
         WHEN p.price > 500000
              AND ( p.price < 1500000 ) THEN 'Price 500k - 1.5M'
         WHEN p.price > 0
              AND ( p.price < 500000 ) THEN 'Price 0 - 500K'
         ELSE '00'
       END                                               AS CustomLabel0
         
FROM   products p
       INNER JOIN files f
               ON p.product_id = f.product_id
       INNER JOIN imagen_google_shopping igs
               ON p.asin = igs.asin
       --inner join cost_of_sold cs on p.product_id = cs.product_id
       INNER JOIN categories c
               ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE  f.main = 1
       AND p.status = 1
       ) Q
```

Obtengo Este es el resultado

```
{
   "id":52789565,
   "title":"9 Bolsas para Aspiradoras para Alergias Panasonic Tipo C C-3 C3, Botes para Aspiradoras, MC-125P, MC125P, MC771, MC772, MC8310, MC8320, MC8330",
   "description":"Diseñado para adaptarse al fabricante original # : MC-125P, MC125P Se adapta a estas series de modelos y otras: Panasonic MC771, MC772 Recipientes Panasonic MC872, MC881, MC883 Recipientes Panasonic MC7310, 7320 Recipientes Panasonic MC8310, MC8320, MC8330 Recipientes Panasonic MC9410, MC9420, MC9430, MC9440 Recipientes Panasonic MC9527, MC Recipientes 9530 El artículo es: Filtración de micrones Bolsa para alergias Atrapa bacterias, ácaros del polvo, etc., hasta 0,1 micrones",
   "link":"https://kiero.co/detalle/52789565",
   "image_link":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51e39MJ8+OL.jpg",
   "additional_image_link":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qx+rDxq+L.jpg,https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/514Yx9UrwqL.jpg",
   "availability":"in_stock",
   "cost_of_good_sold":125608,
   "price":"117014",
   "installment":3250,
   "google_product_category":"Otros productos hogar",
   "product_type":"Hogar > Otros productos hogar",
   "brand":"Panasonic",
   "gtin":null,
   "mpn":"API_52789565",
   "condition":"new",
   "adult":"No",
   "customlabel0":"Price 0 - 500K"
}
```

Pero lo que intento obtener  debe ser de esta manera

```
{
    "id":52789565,
    "title":"9 Bolsas para Aspiradoras para Alergias Panasonic Tipo C C-3 C3, Botes para Aspiradoras, MC-125P, MC125P, MC771, MC772, MC8310, MC8320, MC8330",
    "description":"Diseñado para adaptarse al fabricante original # : MC-125P, MC125P Se adapta a estas series de modelos y otras: Panasonic MC771, MC772 Recipientes Panasonic MC872, MC881, MC883 Recipientes Panasonic MC7310, 7320 Recipientes Panasonic MC8310, MC8320, MC8330 Recipientes Panasonic MC9410, MC9420, MC9430, MC9440 Recipientes Panasonic MC9527, MC Recipientes 9530 El artículo es: Filtración de micrones Bolsa para alergias Atrapa bacterias, ácaros del polvo, etc., hasta 0,1 micrones",
    "link":"https://kiero.co/detalle/52789565",
    "image_link":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51e39MJ8+OL.jpg",
    "additional_image_link":[
        "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qx+rDxq+L.jpg",
       "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/514Yx9UrwqL.jpg"
                            ],       
    "availability":"in_stock",
    "cost_of_good_sold":125608,
    "price": {
        "currency": "COP",
        "value": "p.price"
      },    
    "installment":{
        "months":"36",
        "value":"Round(( p.price / 36 ))"

    },
    "google_product_category":"Otros productos hogar",
    "product_type":"Hogar > Otros productos hogar",
    "brand":"Panasonic",
    "gtin":null,
    "mpn":"API_52789565",
    "condition":"new",
    "adult":"No",
    "customlabel0":"Price 0 - 500K"
 }
```

He intentado con el siguiente script,

```
SELECT to_json(Q.*) FROM
(SELECT p.product_id                                      AS id,
       p.title,
       p.description,
       Concat('https://kiero.co/detalle/', p.product_id) AS link,
       f.url                                             AS image_link,
       igs.selection_url                                 AS
       additional_image_link,
       'in_stock'                                        AS availability,
        jsonb_agg(
                jsonb_build_object(
                    'name', p.price
                )),
       Round(( p.price / 3540 ) * 3800)                  AS cost_of_good_sold,
       Cast(Round(p.price) AS VARCHAR(50))               AS price,
       Round(( p.price / 36 ))                           AS installment,
       c.NAME                                            AS
       google_product_category,
       Replace(c.fullname, '/', ' > ')                   AS product_type,
       CASE
         WHEN brand IS NULL THEN 'kiero'
         ELSE brand
       END                                               AS brand,
       CASE
         WHEN p.upc = '0' THEN NULL
         ELSE p.ean
       END                                               AS gtin,
       Concat('API_', f.product_id)                      AS mpn,
       'new'                                             AS condition,
       CASE
         WHEN p.is_adult_product = 1 THEN 'Si'
         ELSE 'No'
       END                                               AS adult,
       CASE
         WHEN p.price > 5500000 THEN 'Price 5.5M +'
         WHEN p.price > 1500000
              AND ( p.price < 5500000 ) THEN 'Price 1.5 - 5.5M'
         WHEN p.price > 500000
              AND ( p.price < 1500000 ) THEN 'Price 500k - 1.5M'
         WHEN p.price > 0
              AND ( p.price < 500000 ) THEN 'Price 0 - 500K'
         ELSE '00'
       END                                               AS CustomLabel0

FROM   products p
       INNER JOIN files f
               ON p.product_id = f.product_id
       INNER JOIN imagen_google_shopping igs
               ON p.asin = igs.asin
       --inner join cost_of_sold cs on p.product_id = cs.product_id
       INNER JOIN categories c
               ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE  f.main = 1
       AND p.status = 1
    group by p.product_id, p.title, p.description,
             f.url, igs.selection_url, c.name, c.fullname, f.product_id

       ) Q
```

Pero no he obtenido ningun resultado, ¿Depronto pueden guiarme? o una manera optima de obtener el lo esperado?